# .htaccess redirect to subfolder except for some url WP+Joomla

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I've installed a Joomla website in a subfolder of a WordPress site root domain. My goal is to redirect all old url request to new Joomla homepage,  except some url.
Assuming www.exampledomain.com is the WP root site, www.exampledomain.com/newsite/ is the new subfolder Joomla site and www.exampledomain.com/some/ is path not to redirect, how can I modify WP .htaccess?
Note that /some/ is not a root subfolder.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache, you can manually add all of your redirect rules into the WordPress `.htaccess` file. Here's an [explanation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) of how to do it on Apache's website.

Note that Apache will read and apply all of the `.htaccess` files between your server root (e.g. `/var/www/html` by default on a Debian server) and the directory you are serving from (`/newsite` in your example). There's a possibility you'll have conflicting directives in the WordPress `.htaccess` file and the Joomla `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an exception to not apply the rule when it matches the /some path

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some
RewriteRule (.*)  /newsite/$1 [L,R=301]
```